I have issue in my laravel project related to some email configuration
I have a project of laravel which i have deployed on godaddy web hosting economy everything is working fine but when i am trying to purchase some services from the website and when i have checked it on my local environment it's working fine but on live server at the time of checkout process it shows connection could not be established with host smtpout.secureserver.net:stream_socket_client():

Connection could not be established with host smtpout.secureserver.net
:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:465 (Connection timed out)

/home/qs9govzyvf1p/public_html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
        $host = $this->params['host'];
        if (!empty($this->params['protocol'])) {
            $host = $this->params['protocol'].'://'.$host;
        }
        $timeout = 15;
        if (!empty($this->params['timeout'])) {
            $timeout = $this->params['timeout'];
        }
        $options = [];
        if (!empty($this->params['sourceIp'])) {
            $options['socket']['bindto'] = $this->params['sourceIp'].':0';
        }
 
        if (isset($this->params['stream_context_options'])) {
            $options = array_merge($options, $this->params['stream_context_options']);
        }
        $streamContext = stream_context_create($options);
 
        set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) {
            throw new Swift_TransportException('Connection could not be established with host '.$this->params['host'].' :'.$msg);
        });
        try {
            $this->stream = stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
        } finally {
            restore_error_handler();
        }
 
        if (!empty($this->params['blocking'])) {
            stream_set_blocking($this->stream, 1);
        } else {
            stream_set_blocking($this->stream, 0);
        }
        stream_set_timeout($this->stream, $timeout);
        $this->in = &$this->stream;
        $this->out = &$this->stream;
    }
 
    /**
     * Opens a process for input/output.
     */
Arguments
"Connection could not be established with host smtpout.secureserver.net :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:465 (Connect ▶"

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtpout.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@khfm.co.in
MAIL_PASSWORD=admin@123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@khfm.co.in
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Khfm"
MAIL_MAILER=log

tell me the issue or give me some solution to fix it

"tell me the issue"...the error message already tells you what the problem is - your code cannot connect to the specified SMTP server on port 465. As for possible causes: a firewall rule is by far the most likely reason. If you deployed this on a generic, cheap shared hosting service such as godaddy then they probably block most outbound ports from their servers by default. You can contact their support team to check if this is the case, and ask them if they will unblock it for you.

as i see your port in env not match the one in the error
clear the cache and try again

And what have you tried to resolve it, what steps did you take to figure out why the error is happening? Tell me the issue or give me some solution to fix it is not a question fit for a Q&A site. Please read how do I ask a good question? and edit the question accordingly.
